# How to get the component name from current url?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In the angular SPA, I have a button in the header component, and the router-outlet in the main component. What I want is when I navigate so another component (eg: CustomerOverviewComponent), and the current **url** is /customer/customer-overview. When I click that button in the header, I want to call the method of `CustomerOverviewComponent`.

`main.component.html`

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet name="page"></router-outlet>
```

`header.component.html`

```
<button (click)="doSomething()"></button>
```

`header.component.ts`

```
constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRouter: ActivatedRouter)
doSomething() {
  console.log(this.router.url); // if I navigate to customer overview, 
                                // will give me the result like this
                                // /customer/(page:customer-overview)

 console.log(this.activatedRouter.component); // this will print out
                                              // ƒ MainComponent(...){...}
}
```

What I need is inside of the `Header component`, I want to get the component name of the current url. Using `this.router.url` will only give me the actually url, and I dont know how to get the component name from it.

And using `this.activatedRouter.component` will give me ƒ MainComponent(...){...}, I need to call this.activatedRouter.component in `CustomerOverviewComponent` to get something like ƒ CustomerOverviewComponent(...){...}.

Is there any way I could get the `CustomerOverviewComponent` in the header component?

Comment: Use event listener here..

Comment: check this [link](https://blog.lacolaco.net/post/event-broadcasting-in-angular-2/)
& [plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/aJe5SUtFlnpmGXWA5eHk?preview)

Comment: you want to get component class name?

Comment: @Chellappan yes, the exactly component name, like CustomerOverviewComponent, then from the header component make a generic call to the same method with same name inside of each component

Comment: can you please post your router code how you defined, I think using data property in router you can solve your issue

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar Thank you, it works. I add the data property in the router file and solved my problem. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Subject* or *BehaviorSubject* for the same purpose

Create a service and define a subject in it.

```
.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class AppCommonService {

theme = new BehaviorSubject<Number>(0);
toolbarTitle = new BehaviorSubject<String>('');


constructor() { }

}
```

Subscribe to the subject in your Header Component.

```
header.component.ts
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{
constructor(
 private appCommonService: AppCommonService)

 ngOnInit(){
  this.appCommonService.toolbarTitle.subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
  })
 }

 doSomething(){
   //navigate to customer-overview component
 }
}
```

Set *Subject's* value whenever you navigate to a different component

```
customer-overview.component.ts
export class CustomerOverviewComponent implements OnInit{
 constructor(
 private appCommonService: AppCommonService)

 ngOnInit(){
  this.appCommonService.toolbarTitle.next('Customer-Overview');
  })
 }
}
```